# DocuSign - Is there a better way to instantiate the APIclient using the C# sdk in .net core?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using E-signature C# SDK to integrate with DocuSign Api's from my .NET6 based API. As per the documentation ApiClient is instantiated like var client = new ApiClient("base address") .

Is there way to use the middleware to create an instance of the ApiClient so that I can only instantiate it once and inject it in my class, to call the SDK methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple constructors you can use.
You can just do `new ApiClient()` which defaults the `basePath` to be https://www.docusign.net/restapi

You can also use a Configuration object and pass that to the constructor instead of a basePath.

The most advanced constructor is this:

```
public ApiClient(string basePath, string oAuthBasePath, WebProxy proxy = null)
```

This one allows you to specify a different oAuthBasePath and even a WebProxy should you need one.

However, I assume you're actually asking about using dependency injection so that you can have your controllers pass along the singleton.

As it stands right now ApiClient is not implementing any Interface, so you cannot do it directly.

You can create your own class that extends ApiClient, implements some new interface you provide and then you'll be able to get this capability.

You can also take the [code for the C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-csharp-client) and modify it to be an interface (`IApiClient` would probably be the name you want to use)